# C++ Vector of pointers

Tags: c++

For my latest CS homework, I am required to create a class called Movie which holds title, director, year, rating, actors etc.

Then, I am required to read a file which contains a list of this info and store it in a vector of pointers to Movies.

I am not sure what the last line means. Does it mean, I read the file, create multiple Movie objects. Then make a vector of pointers where each element (pointer) points to one of those Movie objects?

Do I just make two vectors - one of pointers and one of Movies and make a one-to-one mapping of the two vectors?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It means something like this:

```
std::vector<Movie *> movies;
```

Then you add to the vector as you read lines:

```
movies.push_back(new Movie(...));
```

Remember to delete all of the `Movie*` objects once you are done with the vector.

Comment: +! Yep - that's what I took from question too

Comment: If I create a vector of ints, I have to push back an int. If it is a vector of bool, I push back a bool.

In your statement, do I push back a Movie object or a Movie pointer?

Comment: You are pushing back a pointer to a (newly created) Movie object.

Comment: gotcha. Now, objects that I have added to the created vector: std::vector<Movie *> movies;

do I access them normally as movies[0], movies[1] etc ?

Comment: @xbonez: movies[0] will give you the first **pointer to a movie** in your vector. This might seem confusing, because if you were to allocate the Movie objects dynamically (without vectors, ie as an array), you'd still be using pointers but movies[0] would give you the object directly. In any case, the rule of them with vectors is that when you declare a vector (like `std::vector<Movie *> movies`), whatever's between the <>'s is what you get out when you access an element. So here, you get a Movie * out - which is a pointer to a movie.

Comment: oops: *In any case, the rule of **thumb** with vectors... (can no longer edit).

Comment: gotcha...thanks. this whole pointers thing is so confusing...ugh

Comment: i have a basic question!, what is the difference between vector<int>* A and vector<int*> A ?, when i use the first one it requires to use -> while the other one requires . only

Comment: Hi, what would be the proper way to delete pointer objects from vector. For example, I decided to movies.erase(movies.begin()), does this guarantees the delete of pointer objects?

Answer (score 16):

As far as I understand, you create a Movie class:

```
class Movie
{
private:
  std::string _title;
  std::string _director;
  int         _year;
  int         _rating;
  std::vector<std::string> actors;
};
```

and having such class, you create a vector instance:

```
std::vector<Movie*> movies;
```

so, you can add any movie to your movies collection. Since you are creating a vector of pointers to movies, do not forget to free the resources allocated by your movie instances OR you could use some smart pointer to deallocate the movies automatically:

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<Movie>> movies;
```

Comment: Or even better use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Movie>>` if the vector is the only object which maintain lifetime of `Movie` objects

Answer (score 3):

By dynamically allocating a Movie object with `new Movie()`, you get a pointer to the new object. You do not need a second vector for the movies, just store the pointers and you can access them. Like Brian wrote, the vector would be defined as

`std::vector<Movie *> movies`

But be aware that the vector will not delete your objects afterwards, which will result in a memory leak. It probably doesn't matter for your homework, but normally you should delete all pointers when you don't need them anymore.

Comment: "It probably doesn't matter for your homework" - I'm not so sure - it sounds like the prof is setting him up for this!!!

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure what the last line means. Does it mean, I read the file, create multiple 
>   Movie objects. Then make a vector of pointers where each element (pointer) points to one of those Movie objects?

I would guess this is what is intended. The intent is probably that you read the data for one movie, allocate an object with `new`, fill the object in with the data, and then push the address of the data onto the `vector` (probably not the best design, but most likely what's intended anyway).

Comment: No, I think what's being pushed onto the vector is actually the pointer. ie `movies.push(new Movie()); movies.back()->getData();` or something.

Comment: @incrediman: Oops, quite right. My fingers skipped a couple of words as I was typing...