# Is it needed to delete a pointer that is not instantiated to a variable?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, pointers

I have a `Base` class, with two derived classes `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` and a factory method that returns a pointer `Base*`.

```
Base* GetClass(int choice)
{
    if (choice == 0)
        return new DerivedA();
    else if (choice == 1)
        return new DerivedB();
    throw std::invalid_argument("no no no");
}
```

Both `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` implement a method, say `GetDouble()`, and this method is the only thing that interests me about constructing either of these classes:

```
double d = GetClass(0)->GetDouble();
```

My question is: when I call GetClass(0) I create a pointer that should be deleted. However, I am not instantiating it to an object. Should I still need to delete it?

Something like:

```
Base* c = GetClass(0);
double d = c->GetDouble();
delete c;
```

How would that work with `std::unique_ptr`?

Thank you in advance.

PS: I think there are related questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361139/c-vector-of-pointers-to-objects) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853438/c-vector-of-pointers), but mine is a little more specific.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I am not instantiating it to an object."*? Of course you're leaking memory (or other resources).

Comment: Return a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` and you don't have trouble thinking about deleting it ;-)

Comment: I mean as the last example that I gave, when I instantiate one of the class first to `Base* c`, then call `c->GetDouble()` and then delete `c`

Comment: @Girardi: "Instantiating" is what you do to templates. The C++ description of the last example would be "Initialize the variable `Base *c`".

Comment: @MSalters thanks for the info =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using `std::unique_ptr`, you wouldn't have the trouble of calling `delete`.

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> GetClass(int choice)
{
    if (choice == 0)
        return std::make_unique<DerivedA>();
    else if (choice == 1)
        return std::make_unique<DerivedB>();
    throw std::invalid_argument("no no no");
}
```

And you can now safely call:

```
double d = GetClass(0)->GetDouble();
```

What happens here is that: `GetClass(0)` will return an `rvalue` that will only be destroyed at the `;`. Hence, chained calls such as `GetClass(0)->func->func->etc();` will still have the object returned by `GetClass()` alive until `;`

Remember `;` is one of C++'s most powerful feature.

Comment: How would I go if I need to pass arguments to construct `DerivedA` and `DerivedB`?

Comment: @Girardi Pass the arguments to `std::make_unique` as parameters for construction.

Comment: @Girardi, pass it as arguments to [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).. Example: `std::make_unique<DerivedA>(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...etc);`

Comment: If you can avoid polymorphism completely, everything would be even better:
std::variant<DerivedA, DerivedB> GetClass(int choice)
{
    if (choice == 0)
        return DerivedA {};
    else if (choice == 1)
        return DerivedB {};
  
    throw std::invalid_argument("no no no");
}

Answer (score 5):

`double d = GetClass(0)->GetDouble();` Is a memory leak.  You `new` up the object in the function and then you return it.  You use the returned object to call a member function and then you discard the pointer at the end of the expression.  Since you no longer have the pointer you can longer call delete and free the memory that you grabed.

Remember every call to `new`/`new[]` needs a matching call to `delete`/`delete[]`

Now that we have smart pointers we can fix this using a `std::unique_ptr`.  The pointer will manage the memory for you and once it goes out of scope it will delete the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You are in fact instantiating an object, but not storing a pointer to it, which is already a memory leak. Anytime you allocate an object with the use of `new`, it is your responsibility as a programmer to ensure is is deleted accordingly.

Your latter example works correctly. Using a `std::unique_ptr` will save you this worry as it automatically deletes its pointed-to object when it is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you still need to `delete` it.

`GetClass` dynamically allocates storage for a `DerivedA` or `DerivedB`. Regardless of whether or not you store the resulting pointer anywhere, the memory will leak if it's not deleted.

As you note, `std::unique_ptr<Base>` solves your problem.

```
double d = GetClass(0)->GetDouble();
```

If `GetClass` returns a `std::unique_ptr`, then it will be destructed at the end of the full-expression containing it, which will delete the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

If you `new` you *must* `delete` (rare exceptions apply of course, like when you intentionally leak objects during shutdown of the program to speed it up and you know the destructors do nothing useful - but that's an edge case). Simple as that. It does not matter if you assign the return value of `new` to a variable or not - memory is still allocated and needs to be released. If you don't keep track of the returned pointer to delete it later it is simply leaked.

Using `std::unique_ptr` helps you by taking ownership of the pointer and releasing it when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope.